# CRUD no longer displaying content after adding new model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've just created a comments model and for some reason my song submissions are no longer showing in the song#index.

In short, initially I had just a songs_controller with the typical CRUD functionality. When I would create a new song it would be posted and displayed in the index. However, after creating the comments model the songs are no longer being displayed (or perhaps, even being created altogether).

I've attached the various pages in a gist below. I will update this post with any additional pages upon request.

https://gist.github.com/Apane/affe60c5b9d0d33cbaf8

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :author_name, :content
end
```

**song.rb**

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user


  has_attached_file :track,
                    :url  => "/assets/songs/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/songs/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"


  validates_attachment :track, :presence => true

  validates :title, length: { minimum: 10 }
  validates :bio, length: { maximum: 300 }


end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :songs

end
```

Comment: Have you checked by looking in the console if a new song is being created and not being displayed.

Comment: yep, save returns false for some reason :(

Comment: Add the Song and Comment models source code to the gist, more than likely you've created a relationship where an inner join is being specified so songs without a comment are not being returned.

Comment: @cfeduke, that makes sense :)  i've added the models to the original post above.

Comment: Can you show us what error is returning when you try saving a song in console by `save!` method?

Comment: in console you can see if you have any errors when a song is saving by doing this: `user = User.find 1`, `song = user.song.new(title: "blabla")` the song won't be saved and to see errors do `song.errors`

Comment: rmagnum2002, getting NoMethodError: undefined method `song' for #<User:0x007f847b60f7f0> :(

Comment: sorry, it should be `song = user.songs.new()` as you have `has_many` relation, than do `song.errors`, you'll see `@messages={}` with errors in it

Comment: @rmagnum2002 :) that worked, 2.0.0p195 :009 > song.errors
 => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f8479c39060 @base=#<Song id: nil, title: nil, artist: nil, bio: nil, track_file_name: nil, track_content_type: nil, track_file_size: nil, track_updated_at: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={}>

Comment: :) not quite, as you didn't call save on it, please do `song = user.songs.create(title: "blabla")`, see the `create()` call instead of `new()`

Comment: there we go ;) <ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f847a22de58 @base=#<Song id: nil, title: "blabla", artist: nil, bio: nil, track_file_name: nil, track_content_type: nil, track_file_size: nil, track_updated_at: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:track=>["can't be blank"], :title=>["is too short (minimum is 10 characters)"]}>

Comment: the strange thing is, those errors don't show when I click submit with blank fields in the actual app anymore. it just redirects to the blank index. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33405/discussion-between-rmagnum2002-and-apane101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when adding a new song in console you have:

```
[2013-07-13T10:07:00.739137 #11358] INFO -- : Started POST "/songs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-13 10:07:00 +0300 
[2013-07-13T10:07:00.739187 #11358] INFO -- : Started POST "/songs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-13 10:07:00 +0300 
[2013-07-13T10:07:00.749151 #11358] INFO -- : Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-13 10:07:00 +0300 
[2013-07-13T10:07:00.749230 #11358] INFO -- : Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-13 10:07:00 +0300
```

this happens because you are using `before_filter :authorize, only: [:create ,:edit, :update, :destroy]`

using Devise you can use the built in filter for controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create ,:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

anyway, the problem was with the filter you have built

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could vote your answer up 100 times. @rmagnum2002, put in great effort, and is a good man!